# Convert table data into flat format using of Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following input data range

[image: Input range]

and the following desired output

[image: Desired output]

The first block with Compals will be always the same - so 5 rows. **Base Unit Current** and **Base Unit Later** blocks will be variable - sometimes eight options and sometimes more than eight options.

I'm very new in excel vba so unfortunately I have no idea how to do that. Please, could anyone help me or give me some advice. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I was wondering the one you looking for called "Pivot"?

Comment: Is it something which can be created by vba and to have desired output?

Comment: I reckon that you mean the first five **columns** will always be the same? It's difficult to point you in the right direction. I'd probably go through the columns and make a [VLOOKUP](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Vlookup.html) for every PCA option.

Comment: No, I meant ODM FCS Date Name Description Base Unit - these rows will be always the same (only 5 rows).

Comment: I just tried it with Pivot but it look like the Pivot could not have the desired output. You have to go through VBA to create your table. The 1st 5 rows should be easy for you, for the Base Unit Current and Later you need calculate the number of option and copy them into the desired table.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder you accept this kind of answer of not? 
Instead of table, I think this kind of pivot may suitable your need: 
I reform the table

[image: table reform]

Create the pivot table

[image: Pivot]

Comment: This looks very close, but it needs to be done in vba and it must look as desired output :-(